# SQL Query - Find biggest price differences in the last 5 months

Tags: mysql

Find the biggest price jump / difference in the last 5 months.
I have a Price_Change table with Product_ID, Price, and Date (Timestamp of change).

I have tried to get all the results of price changes for the last 5 months:

```
SELECT Price, date 
FROM Price_Change
WHERE date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -5, GETDATE())
```

However, I'm stumped on how to calculate the biggest price change and compare on all products. I think I must get the max and min for each product and subtract from each other and then rank the changes.

Any help?

Comment: GETDATE is for sql server not mysql

Comment: Are you looking for price jumps between each day? Please be more clear in your request. As far as getting the biggest, what is this in reference to, biggest 50%, top 10?

Comment: Price_Change logs price changes that  happen irregularly at random times. And within the last 5 months, I need to find the product that had the biggest change in price, which I figured would just be its min price in the last 5 months, subtracted by the max price in the last four months. I figured I would then order by product_ID in descending order and limit by 1 so that only one record shows

Comment: When asking questions it helps to frame the question by providing sample data and expected results. providing a the simplest amount of information that fully describes your problem often leads you to the correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

So as you suggested take the max price minus the min price in that date range for each product order by the pricevariance descending and limit the results by 1.

the keys you were missing is ordering the results (rank) by that price and **limiting** it to the 1.  I'm using your date logic where clause so if it's invalid for your environment that's on you! :P

```
   SELECT PC.Product_ID, Max(PC.Price) - Min(PC.Price) as PriceVar
   FROM Price_Change PC
   WHERE PC.date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -5, GETDATE())
     and PC.Product_Id = PCa.Product_Id
   GROUP BY PC.Product_ID
   ORDER BY PriceVar dec
   LIMIT 1
```